# Canon 600D + Canon 50mm 1.8 STM Lens

Tags: lens, canon-600d

I am a beginner at photography, and I have a Canon 600D, a old model but pretty OK for me.
I am planning to change the kit lens, so i have proffered Canon 50mm 1.8 STM. Because most of the time i prefer to take portrait/ people photo.

All the youtube video reviews for this lens uses canon 6D/60D/7D etc, and at this point i am confused that if Canon 50mm 1.8 STM will work on Canon 600D.

So, can i use **Canon 50mm 1.8 STM** Lens on **Canon 600D** camera? Thanks

Oh and one additional question, will i be able to take photos from a distance with this lens?

Comment: *"will i be able to take photos from a distance with this lens"*  The longer the focal length the narrower the field of view and the further way it is designed to shoot subjects from (generally).  You can certainly takes shots of things far away, but they'll be a small part of your frame.

Comment: @rakibtg All photos are taken from *a* distance. Some photos are taken from relatively short distances, some are taken from relatively medium distances, and some are taken from relatively long distances. What particular distance did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the 50mm f/1.8 STM will work on your 600D. I have used that lens on my 550D for years. The 50mm STM is an EF mount lens; your camera is compatible with all EF mount and EF-S mount lenses.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you will miss by using the EF 50mm f/1.8 STM on the 600D instead of on a newer camera model is the ability to use continuous AF when shooting in video mode. The STM lenses can do that with the 700D and newer. With the 600D you don't have continuous AF with any lens in video mode.

For still photos the EF 50mm f/1.8 STM is fully functional.